# Nuxt 404 error page should redirect to homepage

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js

I am looking for a way to always redirect to homepage when a page doesn't exist using Nuxt.Js.

Our sitemap generation had some problems a few days back and we submitted wrong urls that do not exist. Google Search Console shows a big number of 404 and we want to fix them with 301 redirect to homepage.

I tried this

```
created() {
    this.$router.push(
      this.localePath({
        name: 'index',
        query: {
          e: 'er'
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

and although the page redirects to homepage successfully I think Google will have problems with this since the pages initially renders with 404.

I also tried this

```
  async asyncData({ redirect }) {
    return redirect(301, '/el?e=rnf')
  },
```

but didn't work (same with fetch)

Any ideas on a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried the middleware for 404 with redirect?

Comment: @gleam No, how would I check that?

Comment: add middleware to 404-page. This middleware will only do 301-redirect. https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/

Comment: @gleam How would I only target 404 pages thought? I am not sure if I have access to the error object inside the middleware.

Comment: hm... i'll try to write an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to create a default 404-page in nuxt - just put a file with a name _.vue in your ~/pages/ dir. This is your 404-page :)

*or you can use another method to create such page: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1614 but I have not tried it*

Then add a simple 404-redirect-middleware to this page:

```
// !!! not tested this code !!!
middleware: [
  function({ redirect }) {
    return redirect(301, '/el?e=rnf')
  },
],
```

Comment: I am looking for a better solution that will also work for child pages such as .com/test/test/test. Would that work in this case? :/

Comment: _.vue is global 404-error-page. It will work on any route (ex: /asd/asd/as/das/e/zxvc/s/wde/gw => _.vue => middleware => 301)

Comment: _.vue is also useful to prevent user to access an intermediate route too. Imagine you have a route like `/categories/:categoryId/benefits/:benefitId/details` and you do not want user to access `/categories/:categoryId/benefits/:benefitId`. All you need to do is to create a `_.vue` file at the same directory level of the route you want to ignore, in this case `/categories/_categoryId/benefits`

Answer (score 9):

Never redirect to home if page is not found [as you can see in this Google's article: Create custom 404 pages](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/custom-404-pages?hl=en&visit_id=637566240571379726-2206685189&rd=1)

instead, redirect to 404 error page

Just use `error`

```js
 async asyncData({ params, $content, error }) {
    try {
      const post = await $content('blog', params.slug).fetch()
      return { post }
    } catch (e) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    }
  }
```

do not forget to creat an error page in layout folder `error.vue`

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would advise to create a 404 page which provides a better user experience in comparison to being redirected to a homepage and potentially being confused about what happened.

In order to create a custom error page, just create `error.vue` file in the `layouts folder` and treat it as a page. See the [official documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#error-page). We've implemented this plenty of times and Google has never complained about it.

Still, gleam's solution is clever and if it serves the purpose, very well. Just wanted to point out another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to provide custom routes to your users like `domain.com/<userID>`
then putting a file with a name `_.vue` in your `~/pages/` directory will not work, because you'll need it for your custom user routes.

For maximum flexibility use the layouts folder as mentioned by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9149868/dan)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `_.vue` at `pages` directory with content:

```
<script>
export default {
  asyncData ({ redirect }) {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}
</script>
```